# Can't kill process .gytm

Tags: linux, centos, kill

Using Centos 7 I have a problem with a process that cannot be killed. When I run `htop`, it appears as

```
"/usr/sbin/cloud-agent -k start"
```

and when I run `top` the process is:

```
.gytm
```

When I kill it, it keeps reappearing.

Comment: What is the process doing? What happens when you run 
    cat /proc/$PID/syscall
?

Comment: When it reappears, does it have the same process ID? If not, you killed it successfully, but it was launched again. Its name, "agent", implies that it's probably an essential process that must run at all times. Find out what its parent is; this could give you a clue what it is about.

Comment: Why do you want it killed, anyway?

Comment: it is using the 100% of my cpu, i cannot use yum without having to wait like 5min to download something

Comment: when i run /proc/$PID/syscall it appears as 232 0x4 0x7fff72587bd0 0x400 0x127 0x0 0x8 0x7fff725874a8 0x7f5a76b63fd3